# QT 5 add a custom widget inherited from QGraphicsView to designer

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qgraphicsview

I have a custom widget from modified elastic nodes example. It inherits from QGraphicsView. In the example it is set as a central widget in the main window, so nothing can be added. Here's the code for main from the example:

```
#include "graphwidget.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QTime>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qsrand(QTime(0,0,0).secsTo(QTime::currentTime()));

    GraphWidget *widget = new GraphWidget;

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setCentralWidget(widget);

    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I want to add the widget to the ui form, so that i can add some buttons and input. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing now is making an application.

If you want to make a custom widget in Qt , you need to build it as Custom Designer Widget - a plugin (as Dll).

In Qt creator choose **OtherProject=>Qt Custom Designer Widget** and create a project. You need to build as Release version, not the debug one.

After building, if Qt hasn't already, you need to copy the `.dll` file into `Qt/plugins/designer` and `Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/plugins` -  you will find .dll's there. You also need to build plugin with tool chain, as Qt creator/designer was i.e. VisualStudio 2013 64bit or Mingw - **MUST** be the SAME.

It's not easy, but i wish you luck.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to add QGraphicsView in the ui form and promote it to GraphWidget class.